# Brother QL 800, "Replace media error", Ubuntu/raspberry

Tags: linux, usb, brother-printer, label-printer

My goal is to have a Brother QL-800 label printer connected to a Raspberry Pi to automatically print labels through a script.

I have installed https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql.

It is connected with USB on a raspberry pi 3 with ubuntu bionic server installed. I'm using python 3.0.

When I run it the power led is flashing red and the following error is outputted in the terminal:

```
INFO:brother_ql.backends.helpers:Sending instructions to the printer. Total: 50650 bytes.
ERROR:brother_ql.reader:Error: Replace media error
ERROR:brother_ql.backends.helpers:Errors occured: ['Replace media error']
WARNING:brother_ql.backends.helpers:'printing completed' status not received.
WARNING:brother_ql.backends.helpers:'waiting to receive' status not received.
WARNING:brother_ql.backends.helpers:Printing potentially not successful?
```

I have tried it on Windows with P-touch editor and it prints fine.

I have tried with several different images and both using /dev/usb/lp0 and the id of the device:

`brother_ql --printer usb://04f9:209b --model QL-800 print -l 62x29 --red test.png`
`brother_ql --printer /dev/usb/lp0 --model QL-800 print -l 62x29 --red test.png`

I have also tried to export the binary:

`brother_ql_create --model QL-800 --label-size 62x29 --red test.png > test.bin`

to export the binary file and then

`brother_ql_print test.bin /dev/usb/lp0`

I have searched for the error message, "Replace media error" but no one else seems to have the same issue.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
It works using the --no-cut option so I double-checked the original image size but it is correct, 696x271. I still would like it to be cut.

Comment: My guess would be a bad driver.  It isn't clear why you're using one from a third party.  Check CUPS or download the Linux driver from Brother.

Comment: I thought brother_ql was writing directly to the USB port but I will try to use the brother driver and report back. The reason I use brother_ql from the first place is I want to automate everything, that is not possible from p-touch.

Comment: At least trying the official driver will determine whether it's a driver issue or something else, so you know what problem needs solving.  :-)

Comment: Do you have any example of how to print labels from a terminal using the Linux drivers from brother? That would certainly be the best for me but I have found no other way than with brother_ql.

Comment: Just noticed that pklaus claims the Brother driver doesn't support Linux on ARM, so it won't work on a Rasp. Pi.  I don't know what the story is with CUPS and ARM, or whether there's a CUPS version for Rasp. Pi.  You might be stuck with the pklaus software.  Not properly dealing with a hardware feature is typically a driver issue.  They claim to support that model, so it might be work posting a bug report.  Maybe they can fix it and you'll be good to go.  Worst case, if the only issue is the cutter, it's at least something that can be handled.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm continuing with this issue and will update when I have more information since it probably is very valuable for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the issue was the --label parameter. For some unknown reason

`--label 62x29`

don't work. However, using only

`--label 62`

Works and is cut correctly.

Comment: Kudos on solving this, and thanks for posting the answer.  In 2 days, you'll be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark.  That will indicate that the problem is solved and there's a proven solution here.

Comment: Thanks man you saved me! As i struggled with the same setup quite a bit I'd like to leave this as a sidenote: If you have the QL-800 and the tape the printer came with, the --red is mandatory. (Note to self #RTFM)